# Google Tag Manager, Enhanced Ecommerce Tracking and Single Page App

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

Since there is not much to find about the combination of those three, here is my question:

When a user comes onto the app page, only the first page will be tracked as a pageview, unless you fire tags upon the history change trigger of GTM (automatic) or you send a pageview event for the particular page (manual tracking).

Frequently, SPAs are embedded into traditional round trip pages, so the GTM snippets sits in the head tag, whereas the ecom snippets are placed inside the app.

Lacking of a reload when the user enters the next page in the app, the DL snippet in the head tag is either overwritten or might be appended with new Information.

That creates two questions:

1. Fundamentally: I can just push DL info from inside the app into a GTM snippet placed in a header on a round trip page?
2. Shouldn't I clean up the DL after every new page view inside the app?

I would very much appreciate an answer to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes you should be able to use dataLayer.push within the app. The thing to note is that you don't have to have the GA tag within GTM trigger on the pageview, you could very well set a "SPA-screen-view" event and push that to the dataLayer to trigger a GA tag.
2. You don't need to clear the datalayer after every pageview. Just keep track of the variables you're pushing and capturing. It is very similar in concept as state in ReactJS

**Example:**

Say on one spa-pageview you sent: `{'page-title':'my awesome spa page 1', 'page-url':'/vpv/myapp/page1','event':'SPA-screen-view'}` and on a subsequent page you did only `{'page-url':'/vpv/myapp/page1','event':'SPA-screen-view'}`, but in the GA tag you're capturing both `'page-title'` and `'page-url'`, the second page will have `'page-title':'my awesome spa page 1'`, since it wasn't updated.

Comment: Hi, I am very sure we read the same and only stuff about that topic : )

I am almost sure you refer to hook up page views triggered on Events pushed from inside the app (whichever it maybe ecommerce or simple screenview) instead of history changes noted from the outside.

My question relates to combining the two worlds inside and outside the app. Technically, I am aware that I can use dataLayer.push inside the app, but would there be any troubles with GTM sitting in the round trip header outside the app receiving that Information?

Comment: There are no issues with the GTM snippet being placed outside of the app. You should be able to use it the same way. If you don't want to do custom events through the datalayer, you can also utilize the history change triggers in GTM as well.